# Create conditional sequence in dataframe in R

Tags: r, matrix, seq

Looking to fill a matrix with a conditional sequence. There are multiple breaks in the data but these breaks/spaces must be maintained.

Here is a sample matrix for what I am trying to accomplish. The first column is the original data. The second column is what I am trying to create.

```
try <- matrix(c(rep(0,4),rep(1,3),rep(0,2),rep(1,2), rep(0,4), seq(1,3,1), rep(0,2), seq(4,5,1)),ncol=2)
```

I have tried using seq_long, while loop, etc. but cannot seem to get it working. Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the following two steps solution is what you want.

```
try[, 2] <- ave(try[, 1], try[, 1], FUN = seq_along)
try[try[, 1] == 0, 2] <- 0

try[, 2]
#[1] 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 4 5
```

A one-liner is

```
ave(try[, 1], try[, 1], FUN = function(x) if(any(x == 0)) x else seq_along(x))
#[1] 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 4 5
```

Comment: I think you could also do `try[,2][try[,1] ==1] <- seq(sum(try[,1] == 1))`

Comment: Works perfect. Just what I was aiming for. I opted for the one-liner. Works very quick! Thank you @Rui Barradas

Answer (score 2):

Consider `try` as your data (1st column) you can do:

```
try$second_column <- cumsum(try[,1])*try[,1]
```

Comment: Right, sorry, I misunderstood where the close parenthesis is. I misplaced it at the very end.